# Dynamic text box in powerpoint (Not to an excel tabel)

Tags: powerpoint

I want to add an title in the basic format of my slides.

I have got many layouts in my Slide Master but want to have the same textbox in it.

Is there is a way to add an text box that its value will be linked to one place in the Slide Master so I won't have to change every layout.

Answer (score 0):

Add the text box on the slide master. That will normally add it automatically to all the layouts and hence to all the slides based on the layouts.